# Image is not shown in Firefox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

An image is not shown in Firefox using JavaScript.

This is the code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(val)
    {
      document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="<img src='"+val+"'>"
    }
</script>

<form name="frmlist" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Filename: <INPUT type="file" id="videoupload">
    <INPUT
        type="button"
        id="btn_video"
        onClick="ShowImage(document.getElementById('videoupload').value);" value="Upload">
</form>

<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: The value of the file input will usually only be the filename. In order for this to work the file will have to already exist on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually upload the file yet. Firefox and Google Chrome won't display content stored on the local machine. IE will provided that your internet security level is set at medium. But you most probably don't want that. Your script needs to send the local file to a server first so your file becomes available as a url. Then the browser will be able to show it.